# JSX conditional render not updating based on state change

Tags: jsx, web-component, stenciljs

I'm creating a JSX component with StencilJS and my component isn't re-rendering based on its state change. I have no idea why:

```js
import { Component, Prop, State } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
  tag: "button-popover-group",
})

export class ButtonPopoverContainer{
  @State() showPopover:boolean = false;
  @Prop() popoverContent:JSX.Element;

  toggleShowPopover() {
    this.showPopover = !this.showPopover;
    console.log(this.showPopover);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="rba-something">
        <my-button onClick={this.toggleShowPopover}/>
  
        {this.showPopover ? 
          <my-popover>
            {this.popoverContent}
          </my-popover> : 
          null
        }
      </div>
      
    )
  }
}
```

My console log statement verifies that the state is being changed, but for some reason my popover box is never visible

Comment: There is no state object with stencil

Comment: Sorry, just looked stencil up, will definitely watch out in future comments

Comment: So, how does the component knows when to update? `this.showPopover` is just a class property and you are changing it in your function. It logs the change but if there is no state how does the component render itself? I'm just curious here.

Comment: Ok, answering myself: https://stenciljs.com/docs/decorators/#state Sorry for bothering.

Comment: https://stenciljs.com/docs/decorators#state

Comment: You mind adding some code associated with this example?

Comment: I don't understand your request. The component I posted above is the code associated with it. I'm simply rendering this component inside of another component

Comment: I can't really tell what's wrong just by looking at this piece of code. Doesn't contain any errors so far. That's why I asked you to post other pieces of code that are associated/related to this

Comment: Ok, the answer was to change the toggle function to a fat arrow function, as the binding to 'this' was getting lost in the JSX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the answer was to change the toggle function to a fat arrow function, as the binding to 'this' was getting lost in the JSX

Comment: The first thing I thought was this one, but with a regular, non-bond function how can you see the data changes in the console.log?

Comment: Or do `onClick={this.toggleShowPopover.bind(this)}` as shown in the "Using JSX" docs